# Zend Framework - Is there a script to index static content from Views?

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, lucene

I'm wanting to add a search box onto my website - which is built using Zend Framework 1.6 -  using Zend Search Lucene. The majority of my content is static, and held within Controller Views.

Does anyone have a script that can index content from the views, and add them into the Lucene search database so I can search them?

Many thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea: you could use

```
$doc = Zend_Search_Lucene_Document_Html::loadHTMLFile('http://my.host.domain/path2file');
$index->addDocument($doc);
```

If `allow_url_fopen` is set to `1` the call to `file_get_contents()` used in `Zend_Search_Lucene_Document_Html::__construct()` should be able to open files via an url.